# Getting error while deploying Java project in Netbeans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment

I am getting an error (exceptions) while deploying my project. Some time ago the project was working but now it is not working. Please tell me a solution to get rid of this.

[image]

Comment: enjoy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai

Answer (score 0):

You dont provide any code so i ll answer about the error. Link Failure usually means that there was a problem trying to communicate with a service. This means, it seems like your jsp couldn't connect to your database on a connection level. Do you have your DB instance listening on localhost? Do you have firewalls in place that's preventing communication between your jsp and your DB instance? Have you checked the internet connection? The link? Maybe its usefull to check this [Solving a "communications link failure" with JDBC and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql)

Comment: yes there was a connector issue i fixed and thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to include MySql connector into library. Please check if MySql connector is available in your project library.

Comment: yap thanks for giving your view

Answer (score 0):

As no code is provided, I just go trough troubleshooting from your GlassFish application server. I suppose you are using connection pool to connect to DB. Are you able to ping your connection pool? You might try via admin console or command line :

asadmin> ping-connection-pool myPool